# How to get Attribute Value of Triggered Send (fired using AMPScript) in HTML email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, triggered-send

I have an active triggered send. I am using AMPScript in CloudPage to fire this triggered send. I am passing some attributes to this Triggered send. I need to use the value of these attributes to show it in email.

```
SET @attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Name", "attributeName")
SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Value", @DEColumn2)
AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr)
```

1. But If I use RequestParameter() function, I am not getting any value.
2. Also,if I use personalisation string (%%attributeName%%), triggered send throws validation error.

How can I use the "triggered send" attribute values in HTML email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a data extension associated with your Triggered Send Definition, you just need to do something like this in your email's AMPscript:

```
%%[

var @attributeName
set @attributeName = AttributeValue("attributeName")

]%%
<br>attributeName: %%=v(@attributeName)=%%
```

Reference:

- [**AttributeValue()**](https://ampscript.guide/book/attributevalue/)

Comment: hi Adam, I've been trying to find an SSJS counterpart for that. Any chance you know it?